# Disabling CMD appearing using Remot CMD client

Tags: batch-file, cmd, remote-access

I'm using the remote CMD client to remote into another PC to set off a batch file. The functionality of my batch file works however on the PC that is being remoted the CMD window pops up to say the command is executed.

Does anyone know how I disable this?

The command is:
C:\iperf\RemoteCmdClient.exe X.X.X.XXX "START C:\iperf\BatFiles\KillIP.bat"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `START /min` to start a application minimised:

```
C:\iperf\RemoteCmdClient.exe X.X.X.XXX "START /MIN C:\iperf\BatFiles\KillIP.bat"
```

should do the job.

If you prefer to close the command window don't use `START` at all:

```
C:\iperf\RemoteCmdClient.exe X.X.X.XXX "C:\iperf\BatFiles\KillIP.bat"
```